# displaying one div after all first div in php foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two div for example div1 and div2. Both div is in same loop but having different contents. I want to display all the elements of div1 and then all the elements of div2 in foreach loop. Right now it is showing div1 content and then div2 content. I want to display all the content of div1 first and then all the contents of div2. How to do this in php loop?

```
<?php foreach($array as $val){ ?>
<div id="div1">test</div>
<div id="div2">code</div>
<?php } ?>
```

if array is having three elements :-

//current output :- 
`test code test code test code`

//Expected outpur :- 
`test test test code code code`

Comment: Do you mind posting your current code?

Answer (score 1):

Run two loops, first one for **div1** and second for **div2**, that way you will get this

> I want to display all the content of div1 first and then all the contents of div2

**Ok so you still want to run only 1 loop:** You can take some help from variables

```
$div1=$div2="";
foreach($array as $val){
  $div1.="<div id=\"div1\">$val</div>";   // store in a temporary variable
  $div2.="<div id=\"div2\">$val</div>";
}
echo $div1;        //print 1
echo $div2;        //print 2
```

However in HTML you cant really have multiple elements with same `id`

Comment: That i know we can run two loops but i want to do this in one loop only.

Comment: Without seeing your code no one can solve that then :)

Comment: Real code please, that example can't demonstrate what is really required

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this way..

```
<?php 
    $div1_content = '';
    $div2_content = '';
    foreach($array as $val){ 
        $div1_content .= '<div id="div1">test</div>';
        $div2_content .= '<div id="div2">test</div>';
    } 
    echo $div1_content;
    echo $div2_content;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply i think this will solve my problem. Thanks